# Change or remove "AutoRotation" tag from mp4 video file on Linux

Tags: video, metadata, exiftool

One of my video is upside down. It turns out that the *AutoRotation* metadata is set wrong to `Down` whereas it should be `Up` according to my other videos:

```
$ exiftool -s input.mp4 | grep AutoRotation
AutoRotation                    : Down
```

I tried using `exiftool` from the command line to change the tag:

```
$ exiftool -AutoRotation=Up input.mp4
Warning: Sorry, AutoRotation is not writable
Nothing to do.
```

How can I change (or remove) a specific mp4 tag on linux?

Comment: From what I can tell looking through the Exiftool docs, the `AutoRotation` tag is a GoPro specific tag.  Odds are, unless GoPro provides a program to allow editing of GoPro video data, you can't edit this.  You can probably remove all the GoPro data by remuxing with FFMpeg or a similar tool.  You might also try editing the `Rotation` tag (e.g. `-Rotation=90/180/270`) with exiftool and seeing if that has the desired effect.

Comment: Indeed it's from a GoPro camera and adding the `Rotation` tag is doing the job using  `exiftool -Rotation=0 input.mp4`

I'm surprised to read that there is no standard for tag editing (like on music files).

Can you write an answer ?

Comment: There's really no standard for video metadata beyond the Quicktime spec. Companies like GoPro make their own metadata formats, with each company doing completely different things and often hiding the data as proprietary. As an example, exiftool can decode over 40 different ways of embedding a geotrack in a video file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AutoRotation` tag is a GoPro specific tag and is unlikely to be editable unless GoPro has a program that edits the metadata it embeds.

Using exiftool, a better option would be to edit the `Rotation` tag (e.g. `-Rotation=90/180/270`), which is actually not a single tag but a case of exiftool manipulating multiple tags in order to achieve the rotation desired (see the entry on the [Composite tag page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Composite.html)).

Comment: Just an afterthought, since `AutoRotation` is a GoPro specific tag, it's probably unlikely that there is any video player that even recognizes it in the first place.